# Homology of toric varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology, toric-varieties

In the proof of theorem 5.1.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03261) by Dotsenko, Shadrin, and Vallette, they define this (smooth, normal) toric variety $B(n)$, note that there is a surjective toric morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and then claim that the inverse image of any two points under this map must be homologous. Is this obvious? Is this a particular theorem of toric geometry? What makes this map special compared to a generic continuous projection?

Comment: Do you mean preimages of any two generic points? Also, do you work over ${\mathbb C}$?

Comment: Any two generic points (in the sense that they are arbitrary, not that their closure is the entire space), and working over the complex numbers, yes.

Comment: I did not read their detailed construction, but, on general grounds, you have to assume that points are chosen generically (i.e. you have to exclude the finite subset of $P^1$ consisting of critical values of the morphism to $P^1$). Once you make this assumption,  then the claim has nothing to do with toric varieties or the particular morphism, it is just an elementary fact of differential topology.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference or a theorem name or similar? I have never come across this fact  and while I can construct a hand-wavey argument about considering the boundary of $f^{-1}(P^1\{x_1,x_2})$, I don't see how to make this rigorous. I'm sure I'm just missing something easy, but still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading

*Guillemin, Victor; Pollack, Alan*, Differential topology, Providence, RI: AMS Chelsea Publishing (ISBN 978-0-8218-5193-7/hbk). xviii, 222 p. (2010). [ZBL1420.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1420.57001).

The relevant result is that if $X, Y$ are smooth compact manifolds, $f: X\to Y$ is a smooth map and $B\subset Y$ is a smooth (compact) submanifold with boundary such that $f$ is transversal to $B$ (e.g. if $B$ is contained in the set of regular values of $f$), then $A=f^{-1}(B)$ is also a smooth submanifold with boundary. Moreover, $\partial A= f^{-1}(\partial B)$.

Now, in your case, you have a surjective holomorphic mapping $f: X\to Y=CP^1$, with domain equal to a connected complex manifold $X$, which implies that it has finite set of critical values, I'll call it $C$. In  particular, if $y_1, y_2\in Y\setminus C$ are distinct, there is a smooth simple arc $B$ in $Y\setminus C$ connecting $y_1, y_2$. The preimage $A=f^{-1}(B)$ will be a compact submanifold with boundary, $\partial A= D_1\sqcup D_2= f^{-1}(y_1) \sqcup f^{-1}(y_2)$. With a bit more thought (using the fact that $f$ is holomorphic), you will see that $A$ is orientable (use an orientation of the path $B$). Thus, after orienting $A$, it defines a chain, denoted $(A)$, in the singular homology group of $X$. Ditto $D_1, D_2$ (they are complex submanifolds, hence, carry a natural orientation); they define cycles $(D_1), (D_2)$. Therefore, for an  appropriate orientation on $A$, in the singular chain complex of $X$, we get
$$
\partial (A)= (D_1) - (D_2).
$$
Hence, the cycles $(D_1), (D_2)$ are homologous in $X$.

In general, it is easy to find examples (even for holomorphic maps $P^1\to  P^1$) such that preimages of different points are not homologous to each other. One would need to read the paper you linked to in great detail to find out if this happens in their setting. Most likely, they assumed that the points are chosen generically, just forgot to mention this.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a detailed answer. I wouldn't have thought to use holomorphicity to give an orientation. This has cleared things up a lot